# jQuery addClass and removeClass in if else statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

So I have created a class with a border. called border-check. This border only needs to show when the td.k-editable-area has no value (nothing written in the textarea).

I can add a class with the first line but once I add the if else statement it breaks down and wont add the class. So I'm not sure if its a problem of adding the class again or wether my if else statement is not correctly stated.

```
$("td.k-editable-area").addClass("border-check");

if ("td.k-editable-area" == "") {
    $("td.k-editable-area").addClass("border-check");
} else {
    $("td.k-editable-area").removeClass("border-check");
}
```

Comment: `if($("td.k-editable-area").text().trim() == '')`

Comment: `"td.k-editable-area" == ""` is comparing two strings, which will never be the same.

Comment: Try `.toggleClass` instead. `$("td.k-editable-area").toggleClass("border-check", $("td.k-editable-area").text().trim() == '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, I have ended up finding the answer with your help. Thanks you! The correct code was:

```
 function onEditorChange(e) {
            var text = e.sender.body.innerText;

            if (text.trim() === "") {
                $("td.k-editable-area").addClass("border-check");
            } else {
                $("td.k-editable-area").removeClass("border-check");
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is comparing two different strings.

```
"td.k-editable-area" == "" //false
```

It is not taking value from the element `$("td.k-editable-area")` , so make it

```
if ( $("td.k-editable-area").text().trim() == "") {
```

**Edit**

If this has to be checked for multiple `td`s then

```
$("td.k-editable-area").each( function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if ( $this.text().trim() == "") {
      $this.addClass("border-check");
   } else {
      $this.removeClass("border-check");
   }
})
```

Comment: Note that that condition will only be true if **all** matching elements are blank (it would be only if the first is, but `text` is an unusual function), which I doubt is what the OP wants.

Comment: I put the edit in my code. It does now add my class but still isn't removing it when the value is not empty.

Comment: Do you want to remove when it is empty or add it when it is empty?

Comment: @gurvinder372 add when its empty remove when its filled

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, your condition is testing two strings, which isn't what you want.

If your goal is to add/remove the class on **each** of those `td`s based on whether that specific one is empty, you'll need a loop:

```
$("td.k-editable-area").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("border-check", !$this.text().trim());
});
```

You can't just use

```
// NOT THIS
$("td.k-editable-area").toggleClass("border-check", !$("td.k-editable-area").text().trim());
```

...because that will update the class on **all** elements based on whether they're *all* blank. (With any other jQuery accessor, it would be based on the first one, but `text` is weird.)